# Cant set.header in express

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, cors

This stuff has been bugging me for days now and I am about to go crazy... I am not able to set.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin') or any other header for that matter. I need this to access a remote API. I have downloaded the chrome cors extension and everything works when that is enabled. When I disable I get the beautiful error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

I have tried number of things and even the cors npm module, still the same.

This is my code:

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();

app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;


app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.get('Access-Control-Allow-Origin'));
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});


app.listen(port);
console.log('listen at ' + port);
```

Comment: Have you tried `res.append(...`?

Comment: No I havent.. but tried it now and still doesnt work...

Comment: Which version of `express` you are using?

Comment: I am using version 4.14.0

Comment: `res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` should work. Consider using `res.set(` clears all headers set before. Maybe you are using `res.set` in another location

Comment: Not sure what it should say, but res.headersSent gives me false during app.get('*', func(

Comment: According to code in question, you log `req` instead `res`

Comment: changed my code to: 

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {

  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

Still doesnt work

Comment: Have you checked out your response header in chrome developer tools?

Comment: I am using webpack and react, if that can create any problems?

Comment: And maybe looking at this link be useful https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Checked my headers sent in Chrome, the headers are sent from localhost:8080, but they seem to dissapear when the server sends from localhost:8080/dist/index_bundle.js.

So how do I tackle that problem?

Comment: localhost:8080/dist/index_bundle.js also gives status 304

Comment: Send headers with `sendFile` too. `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html', {put headers here});`

Comment: Is this the right way to do it? This dowsnt seem to work...
var header = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
}
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html', {header});

Comment: The correct one is : `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html', {headers: header});`

Comment: Thanks, it changed the status of localhost:8080/dist/index_bundle.js to 200, but the headers are still lost...

Comment: I see another (maybe) problem. You serve html files using stattic middleware and also serve using get method. If you serve using static middleware don't use get

Comment: changed it to app.use and still the same. And now the status for localhost:8080/dist/index_bundle.js is back at 304

Comment: Aright I thought I fixed it... but didnt..
I changed the order of res.append and express.static and the header is now present at 8080/dist/index_bundle.js in chrome. But I still get the same error!!!

Answer (score 3):

You may be having the problem that your headers are being internally set, but not **exposed**, so you cannot see them on the client side. [Reference Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

In app.use you are missing the header, 'Access-Control-**Expose**-Headers'

Here is an example of how to **expose the response header 'ETag'**. Just add this line into the app.use function.

```
res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "ETag");
```

By default, only the 6 simple response headers are exposed:

1. Cache-Control
2. Content-Language
3. Content-Type
4. Expires
5. Last-Modified
6. Pragma

Here is a list of all the official HTTP headers that can be exposed. They are the list of links on the left

[HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

---

Now, on your client side, to see all of the response headers, including the ones you have exposed, you can use the following code.   [Reference Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders)

```
var stringOfAllResponses = xhr.getAllResponseHeaders();
console.log(stringOfAllResponses);
```

Or to just see one header's value in particular you can use the following code. [Reference Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader)

```
var particularResponseHeader = xhr.getResponseHeader("ETag");
console.log(particularResponseHeader);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this out :

```
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();

function setHeaders(res, path, stat){
res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
}

app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/dist', {setHeaders: setHeaders}));


/*app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});*/

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;


/*(app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.get('Access-Control-Allow-Origin'));
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});*/


app.listen(port);
console.log('listen at ' + port);
```

In `http://localhost:8080/dist/index.html` you can see all headers set before

Comment: Cool! All the headers are there, but I still get the same error when doing a get request to the API...

Comment: API to namecheap. it works when I enable cors with a chrome extension.
I am using axios.get()
And the I get this error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Daniel You say you are using namecheap API's and have a problem with cors? And you are using namecheap API with jquery or node.js?

Comment: I am using the axios module to do a get request towards the namecheap api. So I guess thats node? but its an ajax request.

Comment: @Daniel So it's not related to add cors headers to your static middleware. All adding headers in our example is not relevant to this problem. Which specefic API do you use?

Comment: @Daniel i think you want to add cors headers for your app, so I made this answer

Comment: Hmm, I guess I dont really understand. How is it not relevant? 
I am doing a get request to: 'https://api.sandbox.namecheap.com/xml.response?ApiUser=ncuser&ApiKey=apikey&UserName=ncuser&ClientIp=121.22.123.22&Command=namecheap.domains.check&DomainList=domain1.com,domain2.com'

Comment: @Daniel You request to namecheap API from server side not in browser. So all cors stuff is not relevant here

Comment: ahh.. ok. So how do I send a server side request that includes the right header?

Comment: @Daniel There is no header needed. Just request what you want from `axios.get`

Comment: But how come the request doesnt work and I get the error?

Comment: I have shared my code now. Thanks for sticking with me for so long!!

Comment: @Daniel Ah you call API from front end not server side. So cors headers needed. I'm updating my answer

Comment: @Daniel Set all headers to `*` in `setHeaders` function

Comment: @Daniel Weird. Try with firefox please

Comment: Yeah tell me about it!! Tried firefox but still the same error

Comment: @Daniel Just a blind shot ;) Sorry it seems I can't help anymore

Comment: Thank you for trying!! Nice to know it wasnt me being stupid!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this also:

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'authorization, content-type');
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how my headers are looking in chrome extensions for live headers.....

```
 GET /dist/index_bundle.js HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8080
    Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
    Accept-Language: nb-NO,nb;q=0.8,no;q=0.6,nn;q=0.4,en-US;q=0.2,en;q=0.2
    Origin: http://localhost:8080
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
    X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 54cfead4-1b26-46cd-8014-d16327ce17d7

    HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
    Accept: *
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
    Connection: keep-alive
    Date: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 12:03:29 GMT
    ETag: W/"7ad28-156c157d898"
    Last-Modified: Thu, 25 Aug 2016 10:56:15 GMT
    Origin: *
    X-Powered-By: Express
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case just changing the order solved the issue:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
```